# Microsoft SQL Transaction Logs File Size

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Our .LDF (SQL Server Database Transaction Log File) has grown to 45GB over the course of a year.

We are looking to minimize that file to a maximum of 2GB.

Using SSMS 2008, we had ENABLE AUTOGROWTH with a RESTRICTED FILE GROWTH of 2GB.

Why has the RESTRICTED FILE GROWTH not been respected?

What are the steps we should take to minimize the .LDF file to 2GB and ensure that it respects the RESTRICTED FILE GROWTH.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason you have a very large Transaction Log is because the database is set to FULL recovery mode (tha's normal for production servers), but you do not have a regular TLog backup occurring (and possibly no full backup either?)

A Transaction Log should rarely increase beyond a known operating size, based upon the frequency of Log backups and query workload (and the size of largest clustered index for index rebuilds).  Wanting to shrink your Log is a symptom, and won't fix the real cause.

[How do I reduce transaction log backup size after a full backup?](https://serverfault.com/questions/12793/how-do-i-reduce-transaction-log-backup-size-after-a-full-backup)

Comment: Thanks Mitch!

We currently have Maintenance Plans which runs every night to create and cleanup old .BAK files which are saved on Tapes. Should/can we create Maintenance Plans for T-logs as well? Is it safe to remove the current (backed-up) .LDF file?

Comment: yup.  setting up log backfiles reduces my 200+gb log files to more managable 2gb+ log backups (retained only for a day because i'm doing full backups once a day)

Comment: you should be backing up your transaction log every x hours (every 2 hours is quite common, but depends on the activity in your environment.)  I can't comment how how long you should keep your backups, but NO you should not delete a .trn backup, unless its older than your retention period.

Comment: @Alex, you should be able to scehdule log backups with maintenance plans.  currenlty what i'm doing is retaining a one day set of full backups and log backups locally while the full backup gets backed up to tape every day.  the maintenance plan cleans up anything older than 1 day (of course after the backup runs)

Comment: We back up our transaction log every 15 minutes becasue we can't afford to lose data. A regular backup won't help keep the log file small, you have to actually back up the log.